# Jump Lists not showing for Office programs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, taskbar, microsoft-office-2013, jumplist

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium. I installed Office 2010 on this laptop, and I noticed that Jump Lists were not showing. If I pin Word, Excel or PowerPoint to the taskbar or start menu, there is no Jump List menu where recent documents are shown and I can pin documents.

The Jump List menu does work (in both the taskbar and Start Menu) for Outlook and other programs like Windows Explorer and Skype. The feature never worked since I got this new laptop.

I used this feature all the time on my old laptop. Does anyone have any ideas about why Jump Lists aren't showing for Word, Excel or PowerPoint?

Here is what I have tried:

- Deleted all files in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` and `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations`
- Verified that file extensions for Office documents are correctly associated with Office programs
- Uninstalled Office 2010 and installed Office 2013 (which is currently installed). Installed Service Pack 1 and all of the latest updates for Office 2013.
- Verified that the following boxes are checked in Taskbar and Start Menu Properties:
  [image: Taskbar and Start Menu Properties]

[image: Start Menu]
[image: Taskbar]

Comment: have you installed the Office 2013 SP1?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes. SP1 and all of the latest updates are installed for Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I see that this has not been comprehensively solved yet.  I continue to search for fixes for myself.

I now believe that the problem is related to file associations - particularly with starter versions.  In my case, this laptop probably came preloaded with starter 2010, and I installed 2013 before uninstalling it.

I see registry entries still calling out starter even after it's long gone from my system, so I will dive at that.  Hopefully some registry wizards will jump in and help out!

---UPDATE---

Well, I tooled around in the registry and saw what to fix in, but all of the new Office entries (not the file extensions, but the class identifiers and whatnot) were too much to wrap my head around.  So, nuke solution, which employs built-in repair:

in /HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, I deleted the identifiers that mentioned Excel (Excel, Excel.Chart, Excel.Sheet.12, etc.), Word, and Powerpoint.

For good measure, I also deleted the clusters of entries for Excel, Word, and Powerpoint file extensions (.xls, .doc, .ppt), which totaled maybe 20 for Excel, 10 for Word, and 15 for Powerpoint.

I then let Office repair itself with Control Panel > Programs > Microsoft Office (blah blah) > Change > Repair  (I chose quick repair).  The jump menus immediately started working again, at least for Excel.

I believe that deleting and repairing the identifiers alone would be enough.  I should mention that I've also tried the fix with clearing "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations", so it might have to be used in conjunction with the registry repair.  Hope this helps!